# Taking user input from UITextField as float or double

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, but what I am trying to accomplish is taking user input from a UITextField **(decimal pad)** and storing it as a *double* for calculation with similar input from a UITextField that is an *integer*.

I've tried a multitude of things and none of them are even coming close to what I need it to do. I've done a little bit of searching, but can't seem to get what I'm thinking of, I may be searching the wrong way, though.

As for my current code, I don't have any because what I was using didn't work so I got frustrated and deleted it :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
double doubleVal = [[self.yourTextField text] doubleValue];
int intVal = [[self.yourOtherTextField text] intValue];
doYourCalculation(doubleVal, intVal);
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, is giving me use of undeclared identifier 'self'.

here is how it looks in my .m 

`#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

double doubleVal = [[self.numberBox text] doubleValue];
int intVal = [[self.percentBox text] intValue];`

Comment: you need to put it in a method.

Comment: Right, sorry. That worked. Thank you for the help!
Still learning and maybe trying to grasp too much at once...